# Old Han Solo and Chewbacca novels

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, books

My mother had some old paperbacks that featured Han Solo and Chewbacca prior to their involvement in the Rebellion.  Anyone have some titles and, perhaps, ISBN's?

Comment: I remember these from when I was young. I should reread them, as I was so young I had trouble understanding them (Grade 3 I think?) There was a similar series based around Lando you should also check out.

Best part of these: It shows star wars can be fun and cool without jedi all over the damn place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe these ones:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Han_Solo_Adventures

I've only read Han Solo's Revenge, it was pretty good.  These, along with "Splinter of the Mind's Eye" were the first spin-off books.

Answer (score 9):

Might be thinking of the Han Solo Trilogy. A good series, I read it once long ago. It covers Han's early years as a pilot and then a smuggler. Without giving away details, there's a lot of interesting information there about Han's history up to A New Hope.

The series has the following titles:

- The Paradise Snare
- The Hutt Gambit
- Rebel Dawn

Comment: The Han Solo Adventures were the ones I was looking for (I remember the covers shown in the article).  I'll give these a read too though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The books were Han Solo at Stars' End / Han Solo's Revenge / Han Solo and the Lost Legacy written by Brian Daley and were republished in 1992 in a compilation available still from Amazon [http://www.amazon.com/The-Han-Solo-Adventures-Revenge/dp/0345379802](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345379802)