# Han Solo's military life?

Tags: star-wars

The question is quite simple: Are there any novels that portray the life of Cadet Han Solo? *The Han Solo Trilogy* tells us about how he completed the admission process. We then hear about how he met Chewbacca a few short paragraphs later, and that's it.

Do we have any info of his life of service to the Empire?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did Han Solo meet Chewbacca?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5596/how-did-han-solo-meet-chewbacca)

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39011/old-han-solo-and-chewbacca-novels

Comment: I've seen that post, unfortunately none of the books listed on the thread answer my question. I'm asking about his military service, his life as a cadet, his interaction with his superiors, you name it. Yes, how he met Chewie is a part of that, but that's not the answer I'm seeking.

Comment: The second link. The Han Solo novels are all there are.

Comment: I'm NOT asking about Chewbacca, I'm NOT asking about Han Solo Trilogy or Adventures. I'm NOT asking about life debts, I'm NOT asking about Han's hatred toward slavery. I'm just asking about how Cadet Solo lived his life during that particular time. The answer to my question is a simple "yes" or "no". I don't think it's that hard? I'll wait, retaining my patience, until someone comes along and actually reads my question, and provides me with an answer. Until then.

Comment: Close-voters: have you not read the clarifications by the OP? He/she is *not* asking about Han's and Chewie's relationship or how they met, but about *Han's military service to the Empire*! How that other question can be considered a duplicate is beyond me.

Comment: @VerpinZal, if the answer you want is "a simple 'yes' or 'no'", then the question is not a good fit for the Stackexchange format, and should be closed for that reason.

Comment: As Photon says, if it's yes or no it's a bad question. If not, just because you don't like that the Trilogy is about the only source doesn't mean that it isn't the answer.

Comment: Actually, yes or no is a perfect fit for SE. If you don't think so, ask on Meta.

Comment: @JohnP If people actually read what the OP is looking for then maybe there would be better quality answers

Comment: [Are questions looking to simply prove or disprove a premise with a yes/no answer a good fit for our site?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1450/5184)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Han Solo and the Corporate Sector Source Book](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo_and_the_Corporate_Sector_Sourcebook)* gives a little bit of extra information such as hinting at how Han got his Corellian Bloodstripe during his time as an Imperial.

But outside of that, no, there are no other books detailing his time serving the Empire.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although the mad Corellian tells nobody about how the Corellian government gave him his bloodstripes, I'd like to hear that story too, maybe in the future.

Answer (score 1):

- Some parts of it were in "The Hutt Gambit" (second book in A.C. Crispin's [Han Solo trilogy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo_Trilogy)); not too much though (it concentrates on Han's saving of Chewie)

  - The main info on the latter is actually in [Chewbacca comics](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca_%28comics%29) - specifically [issue #2](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Chewbacca_2). Again, of course, concentrating on how Han met Chewie.
  - The **original** mention of the slaver story is in 1978's "[The Wookiee Storybook](http://www.theforce.net/image_popup/image_popup_global.asp?Image=timetales/misc/arcana/wookstory07.jpg)".

Aside from that, no more details in canon. (... yet. Disney canon is still being built up)